# Zoom change listener in Google maps api 2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have Google Maps API2 on my web page and i want "zoom_change" event to prevent users from zoomin out.

In google maps API3 there is an event called "zoom_changed" but i cant find the same event for API2 if someone knows please help me.

Comment: The V2 API is deprecated.  You should consider moving your implementation to V3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
....
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
....
GEvent.addListener(map, "zoomend", function(oldzoomlevel, newzoomlevel) {
  alert(oldzoomlevel +" " + newzoomlevel);
});
```

[**Example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/8eH8e/1/)

[**About more GEvents**](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/gevent.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The event is `zoomend`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GMap2.zoomend